# Seeking Guidance for Seamless Dynamic Road Generation in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hello fellow game devs,

I'm currently grappling with a puzzle in Unity as I strive to create a dynamic road generation system for my game. The idea is to spawn a new road GameObject every time the player breezes past a trigger point. Sounds cool, right? Here's where it gets twisty.

The road's movement is influenced by player input, rocking back and forth in the X-axis. Now, every time I birth a new road after the trigger point shenanigans, it doesn't snuggle up exactly next to its road sibling. I need these roads to form a seamless, endless lane based on the player's dance moves.

Here's a snippet to give you a taste:

```
public class RoadGenerator : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject roadPrefab;
    private Vector3 nextRoadPosition;

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            SpawnRoad();
        }
    }

    private void SpawnRoad()
    {
        Instantiate(roadPrefab, nextRoadPosition, Quaternion.identity);
        // What do I do to ensure the new road cuddles up perfectly with the previous one?
        // Considering the player's variable movement in the X-axis.
    }
}
```

This is the simple movement code that i am using to move the platform itself instead of the player. It's attached to the road object.

```
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetAxis("Horizontal")>0)
        {
            transform.position += new Vector3(-4, 0, 0) * Time.deltaTime;
        }
        if (Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") < 0)
        {
            transform.position += new Vector3(4, 0, 0) * Time.deltaTime;
        }
    }
```

Any seasoned Unity maestros have some secret sauce or nuggets of wisdom to ensure my newly spawned roads align flawlessly with the existing ones? Help me keep the road party rolling smoothly! ️

Thank's in advance.

Comment: save the last created road position? and then increase the new position by exactly its width?

Comment: Are you simply selecting from a set of prefabs? If so you probably need to keep track of the road entry and exit position of each prefab. This may need to include rotation/full transforms if your player can turn.

Comment: It would help to see a picture of your prefabs - are they just rectangles? Also, where is `nextRoadPosition` being set? In any case I imagine manipulating the vertices to position up (https://discussions.unity.com/t/dynamically-move-vertices-of-a-mesh/157454) or (pun intended) don't reinvent the wheel: https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/utilities/b-zier-path-creator-136082

Comment: @Absinthe as far as I can tell/understand OP moves in 2D space (only left/right on X axis) .. the question is basically how to calculate the `nextRoadPosition`

Comment: @ derHugo Ah I see, then yeah, += x delta from past pos.

Comment: @derHugo how do i save the last created road position?